# How to calculate the total number of passengers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

I want to code to calculate the total number of adult, child and baby passengers. I tried with jquery but did not count the total number of all the passengers.

Thanks in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/devefrontend/21036h5c/12/

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
    var str = "";
    $(".passenger option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
     $("#count").text(str);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Dewasa <span id="count">0</span></label>
    <select name="adult" class="form-control passenger">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <select name="child" class="form-control passenger">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
    </select>
    <select name="infant" class="form-control passenger">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `str += $(this).text() + " "` should be `str += Number($(this).text())`, where `str` should be initialized to `0`. Make sure you read the values as numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were trying to add strings as numbers. The following code takes the textual values of the options and converts them to numbers.

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
        var count = 0;
        $(".passenger option:selected").each(function() {
            count += parseInt($(this).text());
        });
        $("#count").text(count);
    }).change();
```

```css
label {
  display:block;
  background:skyblue;
  color:#fff;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Dewasa <span id="count">0</span></label>
                  <select name="adult" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name="child" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name="infant" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wn1phe51/

Answer (score 1):

When working with values, make sure to use parseInt(), otherwise Javascript might see it as a string and act accordingly.

Comment: "might" - it definitely will if you add a string as in OPs question:  `var x = 1 + ""; x === "1"`

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the text of the selected option to an `int` value, and to do that use [`parseInt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) function:

```js
$("select").on('change', function() {
        var str = 0;
        $(".passenger option:selected").each(function() {
            str += parseInt($(this).text()) ;
        });
        $("#count").text(str);
    }).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Dewasa <span id="count">0</span></label>
                  <select name="adult" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name="child" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name="infant" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the values to integer if you want to get the total. Update your Code as shown below.

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".passenger option:selected").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#count").text(total);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here if you multilpy by 1, then it implicility convert string(which is number) to number : tot = $(this).text() * 1;

```js
     $("select").on('change', function () {
        var str = 0;
        var tot = 0;
        $(".passenger option:selected").each(function () {
            tot = $(this).text() * 1;
            str = str + tot;
        });
        $("#count").text(str);
    }).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Dewasa <span id="count">0</span></label>
                  <select name="adult" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name="child" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name="infant" class="form-control passenger">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```